# How to change the index property of a linked table field Access ACCDB with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

Basically, my access database is split into frontend and backend. I am using the backend database as a linked table. In one click event I want to change the index property of the linked table field, but to change the field property of the linked table from the front end it says "Design can not be modified, you must do it in the source database". How can I do this with VBA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the official https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Always attempt to write your solution before posting here. If you have code that you need help with, please post that code here.

Comment: I don't know how to change the table field property of a linked database. I can only try if I know how to do it. And then if I can't, I'll post with the code.

Comment: Not sure what you are dealing with, but maybe this link can help...

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm